# Godot 4.0.rc-2 Plugin mutable access to Arrays in SceneTree

Tags: godot

I'm building a editor plugin for connecting nodes (consumers and producers) to one another using a graph editor. I have a `Orchestrator` object that keeps track of all nodes, and creates a pool for each connection. Each node keeps track of which index in the pool array it consumes and produces into. The architecture in itself can be handled in the normal inspector, but with many nodes it gets complicated. When I add a connection in the graph editor, I want to edit the mentioned indices of the nodes involved.

The problem lies in modifying properties carried by nodes in the SceneTree from the plugin.

I have gotten stuck as that doesn't seem possible. If i try to refer to a nodes index, i get:

```
resourceGrapher.gd:77 - Invalid get index 'net_ids'
```

I have also tried using `@export` on the net_id, but to no avail.

```
Array is in read-only state
```

I have tried exporting an integer and setting it, and that works. So I think this relates to arrays specifically.

> Code from other nodes doesn't run in the editor. Your access to other
> nodes is limited. You can access the tree and nodes, and their default
> properties, but you can't access user variables. If you want to do so,
> other nodes have to run in the editor too. AutoLoad nodes cannot be
> accessed in the editor at all.

This quote from the docs seems reasonable, and i understand why that wouldn't be optimal. But how would i work around this? I thought about the editor creating some resource with can be imported into the orchestrator, but I'm not sure this is the right path.

Here follows a little example of what I'm trying to do:

```
# plugin.gd
...
def on_node_registered(sysnode):
    sysnode.net_ids.resize(12)

def on_node_edit_connection_request(a, a_from, b, b_to):
    var node_from = get_sysnode(a)
    var node_to = get_sysnode(b)
    const new_ind = create_new_id()
    node_from.net_ids[a_from] = new_ind
    node_to.net_ids[b_to] = new_ind
```

```
# system_node.gd
@export var net_ids: Array[int] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably these nodes you are trying to work with are a class under your control (after all, you are exporting an `Array` in them). In that case, you can make said class [`tool`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/plugins/running_code_in_the_editor.html) allowing full interaction in the editor. You can use [`is_editor_hint`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_engine.html#class-engine-method-is-editor-hint) to tell when the code is running in the editor or not.

---

If you can't make that class `tool`, I can think of two generic ways to approach this.

One is to use metadata. That is an ephemeral dictionary that every Godot object has. Which you can access with the [`get_meta`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-meta), [`set_meta`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-set-meta), [`remove_meta`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-remove-meta), [`has_meta`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-has-meta) and [`get_meta_list`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-meta-list).

The other is to have your own dictionary. For which you could use the nodes as indexes. Alternatively, you can take advantage of instance ids, which you can use with [`get_instance_id`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-get-instance-id), [`instance_from_id`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_@globalscope.html#class-globalscope-method-instance-from-id) and [`is_instance_id_valid`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_@globalscope.html#class-globalscope-method-is-instance-id-valid) (not to be confused with [`is_instance-valid`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_@globalscope.html#class-globalscope-method-is-instance-valid)).

---

And I can think of a more specific way to approach this, although I'm not sure it is suitable for what you want: making a custom `Resource` class, make it `tool`, and put there whatever you need (i.e. the `Array`s), and then export an instances of it instead (so you don't export the `Array`s, you export the custom `Resource` instances).

---

**Addendum**: You should be able to set a different `Array` to the exported variable from the editor. Which is similar to the case of setting an `int`, which you have already found it works.